# Open New Link with Card Click (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, onclick, href, material-ui

I am using ReactJS Cards for my program

`import Card from 'material-ui/Card/Card';`

I want to go to a link, for example www.google.com, when I press on the card. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
routeTo(){
window.open('http://www.google.com'); //This will open Google in a new 
  }
}

<Card className={classes.card} onClick={()=>this.routeTo()}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => alert("Share")}>
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
```

Comment: <Card className={classes.card} onClick={()=>this.routeTo()}>
// function --
routeTo(){
window.open('http://www.google.com'); //This will open Google in a new 
}

Comment: Hi Saurabh! Could you please elaborate what this code does so that the OP can understand what your code is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
```

instead of `Link` component for external links.